# How can I split a string by words?

Tags: javascript, regex

*I've read many question but haven't found the desired one.*

I have an array of words .
How can I split the string (using regex  ) by the words that in the array  ?

Example

```
var a=['john','paul',...];
var  s = 'The beatles had two leaders , john played the guitar and paul played the bass';
```

My desired result is an array :

```
['The beatles had two leaders , ' , ' played the guitar and ','played the bass']
```

So basically john and paul are the splitters.

What have I tried  :

I've managed to this :

```
var a='The beatles had two leaders , john played the guitar and paul played the bass'

var g= a.split(/(john|paul)/)
console.log(g)
```

Result :

```
["The beatles had two leaders , ", "john", " played the guitar and ", "paul", " played the bass"]
```

But I don't want that paul and john to be in results

**Question:**

How can I split a string via array of words using regex ?

NB if there are many `john` , split by the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason john and paul were in the results is that you included them in a capture group in the regular expression. Remove the `()`:

```
var g = a.split(/john|paul/);
```

...or if you need to group the alternation (you don't if it's on its own like that), use a noncapturing group in the form `(?:john|paul)`:

```
var g = a.split(/blah blah (?:john|paul) blah blah/);
```

You can form the regular expression from the array by using `join` and `new RegExp`:

```
var rex = new RegExp(a.join("|"));
var g = a.split(rex);
```

...but if there could be characters that are special in regular expressions, you'd need to escape them (probably using `map`) first:

```
var rex = new RegExp(a.map(someEscapeFunction).join("|"));
var g = a.split(rex);
```

[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) address creating `someEscapeFunction`, as sadly there's none built into `RegExp`.

Comment: Ouch.I forgot about those capture groups. Thanks.